# Handling In-App Credits better approach

Tags: architecture, payment

I met 2 different approaches to handling in-app credits.

If the problem is defined as:

Allow a customer to purchase credits, which they're allowed to spend on different in-system items. The credits should have an expiration date.

The top-arch solutions can be described as:

**Solution A**

Store the balance of credits on a customer, and have a table tracking different events happening to this balance (purchased/spent).

**Solution B**

Omit balance altogether, and derive the remaining credits based on the events that have happened to the balance (have it as a dynamic field, sort of)

Are there any things to take into consideration when choosing between these two? Is there a third approach or a pattern that should be followed to resolve the problem properly?

Comment: Solution A has all the same data as Solution B, and additionally another datum that *should* equal a value calculable from the data. In A, what happens if there is a disagreement between the table and the summary?

Comment: @Caleth then the events will be considered the source of truth

Answer (score 1):

Banks solved this long ago with transactions. You can store a balance of credits on a customer but that's not the single source of truth. That's just a cache. Every transaction since this customer/account was created is the source of truth. Any "balance" is only a record of what those added up to at one time. You are NEVER assured that this "balance" is current. It's only a record of math being done on the known set of transactions. Some transactions may have occurred but are still pending because their in a queue, in transit, or lost behind a desk. That set is always subject to change. It can even change while those transactions are being added up.

That doesn't mean omit balance. It means be very careful about what you claim balance is.

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world, don't store the balance. Just do the aggregation of all the transactions any time you need a balance. However, this sometimes can be non-feasible for performance/other reasons. There is an option C, which is to calculate and store the balance during some period of the day/week/month/year when it is feasible to do so (overnight batch, year-end, etc), and mark those transactions as 'balance-persisted'. When you need to know the current balance, use the persisted balance plus any non-balance-persisted transactions. Also, if you have some kind of system migration, or you change the nature in which transactions are stored, you might find the system easier to understand and maintain if its got a concept of a balance calculated at a certain time.